# SSRS Grouping by Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that I need to use a Boolean parameter Y/N to Ungroup or Group a particular grouping (Skill) so when a user select Yes it will ungroup the data and No to group the data. Is this possible?

So, I have the following columns below, and I need to add a report parameter Group Field on Skill.. so the article URL that I indicated in this question, has 2 parameter selection 1) Don't Group 2) Skill. When Don't group is selected the row data appears without the grouping and when 2) is selected it is group by skill.  I have added the expression below in the group (Skill) properties.

`=IIF(Parameters!GroupField.Value = "Nothing",1,Fields(IIF(Parameters!GroupField.Value="Nothing","Skill",
Parameters!GroupField.Value)).Value)`

[image]

Comment: yes, it is possibly but depending on the context and complexity of the report, the solution could be different, from just changing the visibility of the totals to having more than one dataset.

Comment: I recommend you go into detail about what you're trying to accomplish with some examples. It's not clear to me what your desired outcome is.

Comment: Found this related article http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+(SSRS)/93760/ , but I don't quite understand Figure 15.

Comment: The article provides how to enable grouping based on different fields. What you want can be achieved more simple. Add a boolean parameter named eg. SkillGroupEnabled and set the group expression to =Iif(Parameters!SkillGroupEnabled.Value = True, Fields.Skill.value, "")  You can also have a similar expression to control group row visibility

Comment: Can you apply the Parameter in 2 different tablix?